# How to get element from another javascript

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, call, element

First, I would like to dynamic title tab.
Title tab change by every single page's `<h2> Something</h2>`
So I tried to make `<h2 id="name">something</h2>` I made title tab page as one single html page. and each of different javascript page has own `<h2>`
I tried to use `var something =document.getElementById("name")` then `document.title=something` like this.
But this main file can't get elements which is in external file.

Is there anyway I can make dynamic title tab?

no jquery.

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: If you're using ReactJS, per the tags on this post, you shouldn't be using `document.getElementById`. Also, if you have multiple elements using the same id, that won't work either. Please add some code to help clarify. When you say "tab", we have no idea if you mean browser tab, app tab, or something else.

Comment: I meant was browser tab and I am using ReactJS

Comment: In index.html  created `<body>` and inside of that every single js code run here. and I made App.js  which import every single js pages. it is routing thing. And I have every single js pages with `const NameofFile =() =>( ......); export default NameOfFile`

Comment: If you're using react, use `<h2>{this.state.someValue}</h2>` instead of `<h2 id="some-id"></h2>` + `document.getElementById("some-id")`

Comment: @NinoFiliu I don't understand first part. so let's say `<h2> StackoverFlow</h2>` then from index.html, how can I bring this for setting up `document.title` browser tab?

Comment: Take a look at Helmet: https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet - This reusable React component will manage all of your changes to the document head.

Answer (score 0):

### Using ReactJS

You can create a component just for the title. Have that component accept a prop called "title" and then display that title.

**Title Component**: your title component can be a *functional component*

```
import React from 'react'; 

export default (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="your class names for this title">
      <h2>{this.props.title}</h2>
    </div>
  )
}
```

This is perfectly fine functional component syntax. Just save the file as "Title.js". And you can import it in your parent component like so:

```
import Title from "./path/of/Title/Title";
```

And that will work just fine. If you are not comfortable with that syntax you can rewrite it like this:

```
const Title = (props) => (
     <div className="your class names for this title">
       <h2>{this.props.title}</h2>
     </div>
);
```

This is perfectly valid as well. Next, let's discuss the parent component. Your parent component is your page. So, let's call this component "Home" just for this example.

**Home Component**: a class component (assuming it will have state but it does not have to be a class component)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
//import Title component 
import Title from "./path/of/Title/Title"; //note: your component should be in a directory that has the same name as the component 

export default class Home extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Title title="insert title here" /> 
        <div>
          Rest of your home component
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

That's it. You have a dynamic title. Now, let's say you want to pass a variable to the prop "title" instead of always hard coding a string. Well, you can update this line:

```
<Title title="insert title here" />
```

to this:

```
<Title title={nameOfVariable} />
```

And if that variable is coming from your state you can do this:

```
<Title title={this.state.nameofvariable} />
```

You can always destructure your state and do this instead:

```
render(){
  const { nameofvariable } = this.state; 
  return (
     <div>
        <Title title={nameofvariable} /> 
        <div>
          Rest of your home component
        </div>
      </div>
  );
```

}

That's all you need. Hope that helps. Good luck.